# Visual Studio 2010 : unhandled win32 exception occurred in devenv.exe[6048]

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, exception

I've been working on my Visual Studio professional 2010 on windows 7 for some time now and suddenly I'm getting this error when I try opening a project. I can create projects without any problem but i cannot reopen them once closed. When I try opening a project I get the not responding message.

I've googled but none of the suggestions is working like using another user account or running the application in safe mode. I even reinstalled it after removing it from my pc but no effect.

Can anyone please help me solve this.

Comment: If you copy the entire project directory to another computer with VS2010 installed, can you open it there?

Comment: @BenVoigt i've tried and i'm able to open projects on another pc

Comment: Just to be sure, your remove-and-reinstall procedure uninstalled all plugins but reinstalled only Visual Studio (no plugins)?

Comment: @BenVoigt Well i haven't installed any plugins after vs installation and during I don't think so either.

Comment: Did you install Visual Studio 2010 SP1 (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691) and the latest rollup (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29082)?

Comment: @jessehouwing yes I installed the latest version.

Comment: Please open the Eventlog where you should find 2 events when Visual Studio crashes, one ERROR "Application Error" and one ERROR ".NET Runtime". The .NET runtime one usually provides a stack trace that will tell you more about the actual thing going wrong. Can you post the contents of that Event Log Item?